# Displaying image on a different page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hallo there

I have and imageField as part of a gridview and would like to know how I can view this image in a different page when I select the row with a button(field).
When I add the information to a database the imageUrl is added to the database and this I tie up with the name of an uploaded image and subsequently the image is displayed in the gridview. 
Is it possible for me to display this image on a different web page as well

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing image in session, why not populate `Session["ImageID"]` value on Button click?
Set gridview's `OnRowCommand` property to a method that will set `Session["ImageID"]` to the current row's DataKey, then do a redirect to that other page that will get value from `Session["ImageID"]` and get image URL for that ID from database. Don't forget to also perform `Session.Remove("ImageID")`. That way you'll keep your session object as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,you can , i think if you store the selected image information in a `Session`.May be, there are other ways , but the first thing comes in my mind in this case using the session.